# Upload progress bar inside modal not working when ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have page where drag and drop upload works , When drag and dropped it opens a modal which has progress bar. The drag and drop functionality works well. When the file is dropped the modal is opened but the progress bar doesn't seem to increase at all. Even after the success response of the ajax call the the progress bar is still the same.

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

</div>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$("html").on("drop", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#myModal').modal('show');


        var dt = e.dataTransfer || (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer);
        var files = e.target.files || (dt && dt.files);
        if (files) {

         for(var i = 0; i<e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length;i++){

           var file_ext = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i].name.split('.').pop();
                console.log(file_ext);
             if ((file_ext == 'pdf') || (file_ext == 'docx') || (file_ext == 'txt')) {
                 console.log('right file');
                    var resume = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i];
                    var resume_name = resume.name;
                    console.log(resume_name);
                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append("resume",resume);
                        var bar = $('.bar');
                        var percent = $('.percent');
                        var status = $('#status');


                  $.ajax({
                      url : '/resume_upload',
                      type : 'POST',
                      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                      mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                      data : form_data,
                      beforeSend: function() {
                               $('#myModal').modal('show');
                               status.empty();
                               var percentVal = '0%';
                               bar.width(percentVal);
                               percent.html(percentVal);
                                },
                               uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                               var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                               bar.width(percentVal);
                               percent.html(percentVal);
                                },

                               success : function(data) {
                                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                   console.log(data.msg);
                                   //alert(data.msg);
                               },
                               processData : false,
                               contentType : false,
                               error : function(xhr ,status ,error){
                                console.log(xhr);
                                alert(xhr);
                               }

                        });

                }
```

And how do i create multiple progress divs when more than one file is dropped.

Comment: Has the progress bar worked outside of the modal?

Comment: If you want to add a div progress bar for every file, you could do something like `for(i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){ /* append progress bar to body */ }`

Comment: the div progress bar not working outside the modal also.